# How and where to pass Variables to a campaign in MailJet?

Tags: php, curl, mailjet

I'm trying to autogenerate a campaign draft with MailJet api v3

1. I created a template on their website in MJML, simple one (templateid is `$tId=829886;`):

> ```
>  <mj-raw> {% for products in var:product %} </mj-raw>
>       <p>{%product.name %}</p>
>       <p>{%product.price%}</p>
>  <mj-raw>{% endfor %}</mj-raw>
> ```
>
> I also included both [[UNSUB_LINK_IT]] and [[UNSUB_LINK_EN]] because of the locale it_IT

2. In my php code I'm testing with :

> ```
> $tId=829886;
> $products=[
>     ["name"=>'Product1','price'=>'free'],
>     ['name'=>'Product2','price'=>'1 mil']
> ];
> ```

3. Campaign draft

> ```
> $body = [
>     'Locale' => "it_IT",
>     'Sender' => "MisterMailjet",
>     'SenderEmail' => "s.s***i@***.p**",
>     'Subject' => "Greetings from Mailjet",
>     'ContactsListID' => "13",
>     'Title' => "Friday newsletter".uniqid(),
>     'EditMode' => 'tool2',
>     'TemplateID'=>$tId,
>     'Variables' => [
>         'products' => $products
>     ], ]; 
> $response = $mj->post(Resources::$Campaigndraft, ['body' => $body]);
> ```

4. I tried passing 'Variables' to `$response = $mj->post(Resources::$CampaigndraftDetailcontent, ['id' => $cId, 'body' => $body]);` but I always get

> Invalid json input: object ""->"TCampaignDraft" has no property
> "Variables"

Can someone link or show me an example of a $Campaigndraft or $CampaigndraftDetailcontent where they pass some variables for a loop, I can't seem to find anything online. I'm not sure if it's even possible to pass vars to campaign anymore. Please any help is appreciated

Comment: Checkout the documentation: https://dev.mailjet.com/reference/email/campaigns/drafts/#v3_post_campaigndraft_draft_ID_detailcontent

It seems like you should use `MJMLContent` to set the data for the campaign.

Comment: apparently you can't inject vars in campaign.. only in normal emails senders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the advanced "Template Language" used for personalization, is only available for so called Transactional messages and not for Campaigns. Thus the `/campaigndraft` resource used to create the Campaign won't recognize the "Variables" or "Vars" properties used to declare the variables within an Send API Call.

Indeed in the guide [here](https://dev.mailjet.com/template-language/) you would see that

> Mailjet Template language is available for transactional messages only.

From what I know there should be a release for Template Language in Campaigns as well, but that would be with the use of Contact Properties instead of Variables.

I hope that helps.